# C++ calender, closes before I can see output

Tags: c++, calendar

So basically I created this calender and when it outputs you can briefly see that it's right but it just closes down, can someone help me to keep it open to display the output?
I know I should know what this is but this took me a long time to do and my mind just isn't in the right place. thanks

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "float.h"
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

using std::stack;

int calendar[6][7];
void cal(int y, int z) // y is number of days and z is the number corresponding 
{                              // to the first day
    int n = 1;
    for (int j = z - 1; j<7; j++)
    {
        calendar[0][j] = n;
        n++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<6 && n <= y; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k<7 && n <= y; k++)
        {
            calendar[i][k] = n;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int d;
    int day;
    cout << "Enter number of days : ";
    cin >> d;
    cout << "Enter first day of the month(1 for monday 7 for sunday..) : ";
    cin >> day; cout << "\n";
    cal(d, day);
    cout << "M       T       W       T       F       S       S" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            cout << calendar[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "" << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using? "stdafx.h" >> If it is MS Visual Studio you can just execute your program with [Ctrl]+F5 instead of F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since noone mentioned it - you can also do `system("pause")` on the Windows system family. It does what you need in the most 'elegant' way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::cin.get()` to keep the window open.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to ask for some input right before the end of main:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
std::cin.ignore();
```

This will wait for the enter key to be hit: since there was just some numeric input done, there is still, at least, a newline in the input buffer. The first line gets rid of any already entered line. The second line then waits for the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use `getchar()` to wait for user input, which is shorter than `std::cin.get()`.